# Polygon with curved sides, and higher-dimensional generalizations

Tags: polynomials, polygons, polyhedra

I am trying to find references about generalizations of polygons with non-straight sides.

I am interested in both the convex and non-convex cases, and particularly in polynomial boundaries, and algorithms to compute their area. References about higher-dimensional analogues (bodies with piecewise polynomial boundaries) and numerical methods to calculate more general functions over such sets would also be highly welcome.

So far, I have been unable to find much myself, but that might be because I am not aware of the correct search terms.

> **Questions:** What are some references and good search terms for the study of non-/convex polygons, -hedra, -topes with curved, especially polynomial, boundaries?

Comment: You might have a look at [semialgebraic sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set) and [subanalytic sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subanalytic_set).

Comment: I know that Stasheff originally realized the [associahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stasheff_polytope#Realization) as what Wikipedia calls a "curvilinear polytope." A cursory search for this term doesn't seem to yield anything too promising.

Comment: Thank you. @AndrewD.Hwang, if you convert your comment to an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: @Eckhard: Done. :) If I knew more about the area, I'd have happily added more exposition. The [Real Algebraic and Analytic Geometry](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/raag) preprint server might be a productive source for "hard details"....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$Just a few search terms:

- A [*semialgebraic set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set) is a finite union of subsets of $\Reals^{n}$, each defined by finitely many polynomial equalities and/or strict inequalities.
- A [*subanalytic set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subanalytic_set) in $\Reals^{n}$ is locally a union of sets defined by finitely many real-analytic inequalities.
- An [*analytic polyhedron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_polyhedron) is a subset of $\Cpx^{n}$ defined by finitely many inequalities $|f(z)| < 1$, with $f$ holomorphic.

Examples include graphs of polynomial functions and relations, a region bounded by such a graph, and the like. Open and closed half-spaces are semialgebraic, so ordinary polyhedra (which are suitable finite intersections of half-spaces) fall under this umbrella.

Answer (score 0):

In Differential Geometry textbook by HW Guggenheimer it is mentioned among exercises $ Liouville $ polar Curves $ r^n = \cos n \theta $ for integer $n$ values. Among them are hyperbolae (equilateral), straight line, circles one through origin and one centered around origin, Lemniscate of Bernoulli etc.

Radius vector makes an angle to curve

$$ = n \theta + ( 2 k -1) \pi/2. $$