# Polyhedron with faces that are not flat

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Short version: Which term generalizes "polyhedron" to include shapes whose faces are not necessarily flat?

Long version:

The finite volume method is not very restrictive when it comes to the shape of the grid cells. [OpenFOAM](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/mesh-description/) (a library that implements FVM), for example, requires that a cell be "contiguous, convex and closed" and defined as "a list of faces". A face is defined by a "list of points such that each two neighbouring points are connected by an edge"; the face center "needs to be inside the face", and not "all points of the face need to be coplanar".

First I thought of describing the class of allowed shapes for a cell as "polyhedra". However, a polyhedron must have flat faces, which is not a requirement for the cell. I wonder if "warped polyhedra" would better describe the shape or if there is an appropriate geometrical term for that class.

Comment: I guess you could call it a topological polyhedron.

Comment: The problem is not with the shape itself, it's with the description. Think of a similar example in plane. If I have two points, it's easy to describe the straight segment that connects them. If you connect them in a more complicated way, you have more parameters, and significantly more computations to perform.

Comment: @Rahul, wouldn't a 3D topological polyhedron still have flat faces?

Comment: What about "curved polyhedron with straight edges"?

Comment: I don't know if Wikipedia is the *best* reference, but an important polytope was originally conceived this way, [the associahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associahedron). Wikipedia describes Stasheff's original realization as a "curvilinear polytope." A web search for this term yields a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734857/polygon-with-curved-sides-and-higher-dimensional-generalizations), because I left a similar comment there. Oh, internet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such faces (rank 2 faces which don't lie in a 2-dimensional plane, or more generally rank-$j$ faces which don't lie in a $j$-dimensional subspace) are commonly called "skew faces". Often they are conceived as "skeletal", so they consist solely of a set of vertices and the edges between them, not necessarily lying in a single plane. It sounds like you want the faces to also include a surface bounded by the straight line-segment edges. Then you need to decide whether or not you want to allow the surfaces to intersect or overlap.

A polyhedron made up of such skew faces can be called a skew polyhedron. Wikipedia has an article on [regular skew polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_skew_polyhedron). See also [Skew polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_polygon).